# Drupal 8 - What is PrivateTempStoreFactory and it's purpose?

Tags: drupal-8

1. Is this the same as php $_sessions?
   Does it use php $_sessions? (edited)
2. When should I use it?
3. What are some down sides of using it?
4. Can or should I use it to store user input and results of forms for later operations?
5. And is it secure? (edited)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a very good articles about [Storing Session Data with Drupal 8](https://atendesigngroup.com/blog/storing-session-data-drupal-8).
It cover exactly all your questions & more !

Take a look at it, the author give you also a lot of other links to help you.

---

Here a short summary:

**1. Is this the same as php $_sessions?**

**Roughly equivalent**. But (and it's an important but) using Drupal 8 services provides needed abstraction and structure for interacting with a global construct. It's part of an overall architecture that allows developers to build and extend complex applications sustainably.

**2. When should I use it?**

In past versions of Drupal, I might have just thrown the data in $_SESSION. In Drupal 8 there's a service for that; actually, two services: use user.private_tempstore and user.shared_tempstore for temporarily storing user-specific and non-user-specific data, respectively.

**3. What are some down sides of using it?**

Knowing POO.

**4. Can or should I use it to store user input in forms for later operations?**

Should.

Answer (score 2):

The private temporary storage differs from session storage in very significant ways and it is *not* intended as a replacement of it.

1. For logged in users, sessions are completely irrelevant, the data stored in the temporary storage is shared among all sessions of a given user, current and future.
2. Only for an anonymous user are sessions relevant: should their sessions expire, the contents is not retrievable any more because it is tied to the session ID. But the data is not stored in the session storage for anonymous users either, only the session ID is relevant.
3. The data expires after a time set on the container parameter called `tempstore.expire` which has nothing to do with the session cookie lifetime (nor is the latter relevant for logged in users).
4. There is metadata associated with each piece of data: the owner (either the logged in user id or a session id) and the updated time.
5. The durability expectations completely differ. Sessions are fundamentally ephemeral. Many places will tie sessions to IP addresses. It is certainly tied to a browser and as such, to a device. As a corollary, if clients can't expect sesssions to last, there's no reason for the server to cling to them heavily: putting the session storage on fast but less durable storage (say, memcached etc) is a completely valid speedup strategy. However, the private temporary storage is durable -- within expire, of course. A typical thing to store in a session is a "flash" message -- the one you set with `drupal_set_message`. If you set one such and then the session gets lost, oh well. Yeah, informing the user would've been nice but oh well. I certainly wouldn't expect to see a flash message follow me across browsers and devices.
6. In theory, a typical thing to store in the private temp storage would be a shopping cart. In practice, this is not done because a) carts, if not for the end user but for the back office are valuable, not temporary data b) when a user logs in, their session data is migrated but their private temp storage is not. WHether this is a bug is debateable, at the time of this writeup I can't find a core issue about this. This is a possible downside. So a Views UI like complex edit is one possible use case but note the Views UI itself uses the shared temporary storage facility, not the private one. In fact, the only usage I can find are node previews.

Comment: Thank you. Very informative. A question for point 1: For logged in users, sessions are completely irrelevant, the data stored in the temporary storage is shared among all sessions of a given user, current and future.- How to clear the tempstore storage data for a new session of the user?

Comment: New questions should go to drupal.stackexchange.com